# Django channels error when attempting to serve static files with devserver

Tags: django, django-channels, django-staticfiles

I moved my project into another environment and after installing the dependencies and attempting to run the manage.py runserver - devserver I get the following error when static files are requested.
Quite frankly i'm completely lost with this error, has anyone an idea what this is about?

```
    HTTP GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css 500 [0.21, 127.0.0.1:59982]
Exception inside application: async_to_sync can only be applied to async functions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maxehleny/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-EdbyOLs2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 41, in __call__
    dict(scope, static_base_url=self.base_url), receive, send
  File "/home/maxehleny/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-EdbyOLs2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 56, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxehleny/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-EdbyOLs2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 198, in __call__
    await self.handle(scope, async_to_sync(send), body_stream)
  File "/home/maxehleny/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-EdbyOLs2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 105, in __init__
    raise TypeError("async_to_sync can only be applied to async functions.")
TypeError: async_to_sync can only be applied to async functions.
```

I  have got little to no idea where the issue could lie since I don't see how this  coming up  relates to my own code. If I comment out channels everything else works fine.

**Edit2** downgrading to asgiref==3.2.10 as per ladruas answer worked for me aswell.

There seems to be an incompatibility between
channels==3.0.3
asgiref==3.3.10

Comment: See if you can modify the title to also mention static files not being served when Debug=True, as this is what the problem looks like initally, if you are only debugging your own code and not Django itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added `asgiref==3.2.10` to my `requirements.txt` file and it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I downgraded from asgiref 3.3.10 to your version and now it works as well! Thanks so much. I thought it was a dependency issue, just could not pinpoint where.

Comment: When installing Django 3.2.4 via pip, it gave me an error, saying that 3.2.10 was incompatible, and that I had to use 3.3.2 or higher. However, 3.3.2 gives me the above error, and downgrading to 3.2.10 has given me no issues.

At least so far, pip seems to be wrong